# Solving Lasso via ADMM

Tags: algorithms, optimization

I have a question regarding the theory behing solving Lasso's optimization problem via ADMM.

Let's look at this pdf https://candes.su.domains/teaching/math301/Lectures/Consensus.pdf.

First rewrite the problem (26.1) as (26.2), by adding the variable $z$, this is clear.

What is $y$ in the augmented Lagrangian (just one row below 26.2 in the pdf)? The expression is
$\lVert Ax-b\rVert^2 + \lambda |z| + \rho \langle y, z-x\rangle + \frac{\rho}2 \lVert z-x\rVert^2$ (let's call it (3).

Specifically how do we go from the generic Langrangian formulation $f(x) + g(z) + \rho |x-z| +  \frac{\rho}2 \lVert z-x\rVert^2$ to (3), which contains the multiplication with $y$?

Comment: Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: thank you, I've edited the question